# Angular passing image to components

Tags: angular

im starting out with angular and i have to build a small project for school..
I have a node backend which sends images via base64 to my angular service
...

```
imageService.getUserImagesFromDB(id, (result) => {                                    
            for (const imageObj in result) {
                if (result.hasOwnProperty(imageObj)) {
                    const element = result[imageObj];                     
                    const imagePath = path.resolve('.' + element.img_path);
                    imageFromFileSystem = fs.readFileSync(imagePath);                                                            
                    const base64 = Buffer.from(imageFromFileSystem).toString('base64') ;
                    imagesFromFileSystem.push( { email: email, file: base64, timestamp: element.timestamp });                                                                                                                     
                }
            }                                                               
            res.send( imagesFromFileSystem )
        })
```

...

...

```
getUserImages(email: string): any {
const imgUrl = "http://localhost:3000/gallery/" + email;
return this.http.get(imgUrl);
```

}

...
 and those images are rendered by a component

...

```
const imageUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:image/jpg;base64, ' + imgFile.file);                                                                 
        this.userImages.push(new UserImage(imgFile.email, imageUrl, imgFile.timestamp);
```

...

...

```
<div class="container">
<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="200px">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let x of userImages" [colspan]="x.col" [rowspan]="1">
        <a routerLink="/image/..."><img width="270" align="center" mat-image id="img" [src]="x.img_url64" alt=""></a>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

...

and i have some sort of gallery.

Now i would like to click on one of those images and a new component should open with that image for comment purposes. But I really have a hard time to pass the image to a new component.
Well i could fetch the image again from the backend but this seems laboroius...
Any Idea how i could implement this...?
And please don t cut my head off..I m just starting out ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image will be cached by the browser so it won't refetch the same image again, unless the path for the image changes in someway. Just use the url for the image, instead of trying to pass the 'image' around as a prop or something. By that I mean you can just your image tags and what not and put it as the src. NOTE: IF you send a GET request it will request from that path again.

Comment: Soory, I don t understand what you mean..Could you clarify?

Comment: Basically you're over thinking this. You don't have to worry about any of this. Just used the image as you normally would in HTML. The image file will be cached (stored) by your browser. It will only request it once. Just use image tags and set the path for the image as the src.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, 
you can create a globle service and pass `x.img_url64` in that service as data by click of a function,

in html  **(click)="passImage(x.ima_url64)"**

```
<a routerLink="/image/...">
       <img width="270" align="center" mat-image id="img" [src]="x.img_url64" alt="" (click)="passImage(x.ima_url64)">
</a>"
```

ts

```
passImage(image){
   this.globleService.image = image;
}
```

in the other component's ngOnInit function you can assign it to a local variable again,

```
let image = this.globleService.image;
```